# Mouse cursor disappears after using touch screen; Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen, cursor, mutter

[Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v0qltu/mouse_cursor_disappears_after_using_touch_screen/)

When I'm using the touch screen on my laptop, the mouse cursor disappears as expected.  But then, when I switch back to the touch pad the cursor remains invisible while selecting objects until I hover over the dock or top bar.  This only happens in X11 and Wayland doesn't work with my 2 in 1's configuration (Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15IML).  Wayland refuses to take any commands from my accelerometer.  I am also using TouchEgg but it doesn't seem to be the problem as disabling the service doesn't fix the problem.  Also, changing the cursor size in accessibility doesn't fix it either.  This problem was not present in Ubuntu 21.10.  Any suggestions or others with the same problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Using X11 on a Samsung 2-in-1 laptop.

Comment: Same problem here. Sometimes the mouse pointer also disappears randomly, not sure why. Dell XPS 9310.

Comment: Same here, Dell 9510, Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome 42.

Comment: I also experience this, and it also seems to disappear randomly sometimes too. The only way to get it back is to restart, LTS 22.04 is pretty frustrating so far. Late 2019 HP Spectre x360.

Comment: Although this is no solution try hovering over taskbar instead of restart. Works for me :)

Comment: In my case this command is works well. System Lenovo legion.
Command: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the measures work, consider uninstalling and reinstalling the mouse drivers. Choose "Additional mouse options" under "Settings" > "Devices" > "Mouse & Touchpad" to accomplish this. Next click the "Uninstall" button after choosing the "Hardware" tab and your mouse. The mouse drivers will then automatically reinstall after you restart your computer.